# Sending text to pole display (Posiflex PD/2608/UE) using JPOS libraries in Java program

Tags: javapos

I am working on development of a POS. there is a requirement which to display total amount in the pole customer display(Posiflex PD/2608/UE) using java.
I was referring to many solutions of Stack over flow but I could not find what i want.

Here is what I exactly want .

I need to send ,and clear text to Posiflex PD/2608/UE pole display using JPOS libraries or any other way using java. If any one can give me the code example or proper reference

Answer (score 0):

You could be more lucky if you tag your question as javapos, that's the correct project tag, jpos is mainly for iso8583 development, it does not address the end point hardware.